# Build Diamond with '#" with methods

Tags: ruby, function, methods

I am stuck in my program which is to build a rhombus. I want to build a diamond with one pyramid going up (`full_pyramid`) and another pyramid going down (`wtf_pyramid`). I would like to glue the 2 so to make a diamond via the `perform` method, but I am stuck. I don't know how to get the values ​​of "etages" to put them in my `wtf_pyramid` method.

I would like to solve my problem and know how.

Thanks in advance and sorry for my english!

```rb
def ask_etages
  puts "Salut, bienvenue dans ma super pyramide ! Combien d'étages veux-tu ?"
  print '>'
  gets.chomp
end

def full_pyramid(etages)
  espace = etages.to_i - 1
  carre = 1

  etages.to_i.times do
    espace.times do
      print ' '
    end
    espace -= 1
    carre.times do
      print '#'
    end
    carre += 2
    puts ' '
  end
end

def wtf_pyramid(etages)
  espace = 0
  carre = etages.to_i * 2 - 1

  etages.to_i.times do
    espace.times do
      print ' '
    end
    espace += 1
    carre.times do
      print '#'
    end
    carre -= 2
    puts ' '
  end
end

def perform
  full_pyramid(ask_etages)
  wtf_pyramid
end

perform
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are almost there. In your `perform` method, try to save the result of your `ask_etages` method to a variable. Then you can re-use this variable as input for both your `full_pyramid` and your `wtf_pyramid` methods.

I think this might be a homework or personal practice question, so I'll give you these hints instead of writing it out for you.